# Get project cost monthly on MS Project SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, ms-project

I'm building some custom reports for the company I work for about its projects.

I have do get the cost of a project month by month and show this on an excel sheet.

However, I'm struggling to find how Cube summarize this data.

So far, I've got this:

```
declare @res_name as nvarchar(510)
declare @begin_date as datetime
declare @end_date as datetime
 -- set these variables
select @res_name = 'Team Member'
select @begin_date = '2013-01-01'
select @end_date = '2013-12-31'
 -- end variables
select    
       p.WPROJ_ID as Project_ID,
       PROJ_NAME as Project,
       month(ASSN_START_DATE) as StartMonth,
       year(ASSN_START_DATE) as StartYear,
       SUM(AssignmentActualCost) as Cost,
       SUM(ASSN_ACT_WORK)/60000 as Assigned_Work,
       SUM(ASSN_REM_WORK)/60000 as Remaining_Work
from     
      MSP_WEB_PROJECTS p,
      MSP_WEB_ASSIGNMENTS a,
      MSP_VIEW_PROJ_ASSN_STD vpa
where   p.WPROJ_ID = 489
and     a.WPROJ_ID = p.WPROJ_ID
and     vpa.WPROJ_ID = p.WPROJ_ID
and     ASSN_START_DATE Between @begin_date And @end_date
group by month(ASSN_START_DATE), year(ASSN_START_DATE), PROJ_NAME, p.WPROJ_ID
order by year(ASSN_START_DATE), month(ASSN_START_DATE)
```

It shows some data, but they are very different from the showed by CUBE.

What I need to know is which table stores the information about cost of a know task or project, I don't know how it does it.

Thank's in advance.

Comment: Looking at a transactional database and a cube based off a data warehouse are going to be completely different.  Is the cube built off the same tables?  Generally, a cube preaggregates all those values, which is the whole purpose of one.

Comment: Well, it looks very strange. There are some appointments made that should appear on MSP_WEB_ASSIGNMENTS, but they don't. Microsoft documentation about this is very poor.

Comment: You mention a cube.  Who built it and could you ask them where they got the data?  Are you sure you have your joins and criteria correct as well for the assignment you are trying to find?

Comment: In deed, whoever did this no longer works at the company anymore, I'm kind of playing blind on this, guessing by the name of the tables.